# Can I split a shell body using a cone as the splitting surface?

Tags: fusion360

I'm trying to model a "mushroom-like" object. I created the stem and the top part and shelled them to a body with 5mm walls. I also need to split the top part into two parts which I will later on fit one over the other (I need to place some components inside the mushroom).

I tried to use the split tool to do it but it failed with a "Compute failed" error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Here is the [`f3d` file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JVnfxSn3SHt9A2gUfyynLznD-mzK7UfC/view?usp=sharing), but I also attach screenshots here as it might be easier..

This is the object itself:

[image: "Mushroom-like" object]

A cross section of the mushroom top and the splitting surface I've created (just revolved a line to create a cone):

[image: Cross section of the mushroom top and the splitting surface]

Notice that the top of the cone doesn't touch the body. I originally thought that this could be the problem but it didn't help.

When I use the splitting tool I don't check the "extend splitting tools", but get a "Compute Failed".

Any ideas? If I'm doing it wrong - is there any other way that I could split the object?

Comment: While i'm not sure if it's totally impossible to do this operation, I haven't been able to figure it out myself. My best "Hacky" solution would be to use the Combine tool in Intersect/Cut mode, making two copies of the original body to work with.